# Forzar placeholder en Chrome

Tags: html, html5

Resulta que tengo un problema de incompatibilidad diría yo.

Simplificando, tengo un `input` en HTML5 de tipo `date`, el cual en Firefox se muestra un placeholder predeterminado por Firefox que es este:

[image: input date de Firefox]

Ahora en Chrome, se muestra la casilla en blanco y ni poniendo un atributo `placeholder` o un `value` se muestra un texto, no quiero decir que no funcione, porque muestra el `datepicker` digamos.

¿Alguno tiene alguna idea de cómo compensar esto?

Comment: Cuando pongo un input type date en chrome me muestra mm/dd/yyyy a ti no?

Comment: En chrome a mi me sale `dd-mm-yyyy` con `type="date"`. Pero bueno, Firefox y chrome incorporan formas distintas para introducir la fecha. Para unificar en todos los navegadores sugeriría que crearas o consiguieras un datepicker en Javascript.

Comment: Está bien, entonces seré un caso aislado, gracias por comentarlo y disculpen la molestia.

Comment: En Chrome para Mac el campo de tipo `date` puedo ver que tiene `mm/dd/yyyy` y cada uno de los campos se puede actualizar manualmente o de forma global con el triángulo. 

Una opción que puedes seguir es con JavaScript controlar el tipo de `input`: por defecto, si no está enfocado o está vacío, tenerlo como tipo `text` que te permite tener un placeholder sin problemas. Y si está enfocado o tiene valor, ponerlo como tipo `date`. El problema de este método es que el calendario no se abriría directamente. Otra opción sería poner un label/placeholder como texto encima del campo

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="date" name="" id="" placeholder="dd / mm / aaaa">
</body>
</html>
```

Que opine la gente, pero yo estoy en chrome y veo el placeholder.

1. Inspecciona el HTML y mira si verdaderamente el valor está ahí o no.
   Si el valor está, entonces no hay truco ni cartón, el valor si está, está.
2. Ahora...si el valor está, entonces lo que pasa es que, no lo vemos. Prueba arrastrar el ratón por encima del picker, como si quisieras seleccionar el texto, si lo ves seleccionado, entonces lo que te falta es aplicar estilos al texto que contiene un input. ¿Quizás tu fondo es blanco y el texto en chrome por alguna razón se queda en blanco?

Dime si ves el `input` de **stackoverflow** correctamente, y no quedaría de otra que los estilos.

Por último, te animaría a compartir algo de código, puede ser que se nos pase algo, una comilla, un cierre de algo y no lo vemos.

PD: Por último y se me ha ocurrido tras publicar. Si tu situas el valor en el html, y tras cargar la web, desaparece al inspeccionar, entonces hay algo, Javascript al 99% que lo está borrando